# How do you get pyapns (python push notification) working on a mac?

Tags: django, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

pyapns appears to be the most popular push notification package for python.  However, it does not appear to work on a mac running mountain lion.  I am using a mac for development.

```
https://github.com/samuraisam/pyapns
```

> pyapns is an APNS provider that you install on your server and access
>   through XML-RPC. To install you will need Python, Twisted and
>   pyOpenSSL. It's also recommended to install python-epoll for best
>   performance (if epoll is not available, like on Mac OS X, you may want
>   to use another library, like py-kqueue). If you like easy_install try
>   (it should take care of the dependancies for you):

I try to install pyapns in my virtualen on my mac, and python-epoll sure enough does not work.  The paragraph above states that you can install py-kqueue, which I have by typing in: pip install py-kqueue.  No errors.  But when I try to start up the server using the line:  `twistd -r epoll web --class=pyapns.server.APNSServer --port=7077`

I received this error:

```
...  bin/twistd: The specified reactor cannot be used, failed with error: cannot import name epoll.
See the list of available reactors with --help-reactors
```

Is there any hope to set up a python apns server on a mac?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Solution is two-fold:

1. If you are using virtualenv, make sure that you have activated it so that step 2's package is installed in your virtualenv and not your system's python.
2. pip install py-kqueue
3. Substitute the words kqueue for epoll when you want to start pyapns, like below:  epoll doesn't exist on a mac.

   twistd -r kqueue web --class=pyapns.server.APNSServer --port=7077